# E2E Encrypted group calls and messaging (plug'n'play solution)

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for something similar to Skype I guess.
Here are the important main features that I need:

- Easy "plug'n'play"-like solution (like Skype for example)
- Safe end to end encryption for calls and messages
- Normal two person calls
- Group calls
- Normal two person messaging
- Group messaging
- At least run on Windows (Linux and Mac OSX support would be great, too.)

I read about "Wire", but it's e2e encryption feature is limited to calls, messages are decrypted on their servers...
I also read about OTR, which according to Snowden is safe (for the time being) if implemented correctly. But that on the other hand does only work for messages and not for calls.
And then there is the "MEGA Chat". It's browser based (from what I've read) and thus it has to rely on flash, am I correct? And I don't trust flash. I also don't know if MEGA is using proper end to end encryption and in an older article I read it doesn't support group calls/messaging (yet).. not sure if that's implemented now.

So yeah, are there any solutions?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't do product recommendations. But you might be more successful on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com By the way: just because a chat system is browser-based does not necessarily mean that it has to be based on adobe flash. Javascript got surprisingly powerful in the past few years.